Detecting a changed SID for windows login
As an example, imagine you have created a login for a local windows group, e.g. machine_name\group_name
You rebuild the server (new physical machine) with the same machine name (machine_name), attach the old drives to it, including SQL server.  The group has been recreated as well.
But it is a new OS installation.  As such, the new machine_name\group_name will have a new SID, and will not actually work.
Later on, in general, how can we detect a Windows login SID is no longer valid so we know we need to recreate the login?
SELECT SUSER_SID(machine_name\group_name) is still returning the old SID (as stored in sys.server_principals).  [sys].[sp_validatelogins] doesn't report anything either.
It seems that SUSER_SID looks at sys.server_principals first, so we're at a loss for how to detect this.

We have found two ways but they are destructive:


DROP the login and do SELECT SUSER_SID(machine_name\group_name) it will show the correct Windows SID of the new group instead of the old group



rename the new group to machine_name\group_name2 and do SELECT SUSER_SID(machine_name\group_name2) it will return the correct Windows SID of the new group instead of the old group


"How can we detect the login's SID is no longer valid so we know we need to recreate the login?" - Little confused on this question. You would implicitly know any time you rebuild a server. So your process should entail dropping and re-adding the Login on your SQL Server whenever you do this.

Doesn't building the machine from scratch, even with the same name, result in the local computer identifier part of the SID being different? So you can look at that part of the SID to tell which are "old" and which are "new".

@J.D. managing the login is part of a scripted idempotent deployment process.  we do not wish to have manual steps that if not followed cause things to break in ways that are hard to detect

@DougDeden yes, just so.  Or even just deleting and recreating the group without changing the machine.  But how can you determine that from SQL?  SUSER_SID doesn't provide that new SID if a login with that name already exists -- instead it just returns the old SID from that login (which is no longer accurate)

@MarkSowul "managing the login is part of a scripted idempotent deployment process" - That's fine, so make it part of your automated process to always recreate the Login, because again, it always will need to be if you are rebuilding the server.

This question is to detect a changed SID, in order to avoid constantly dropping and recreating the login unnecessarily

Frame challenge 1: Don't use local Windows accounts for SQL logins. Use domain accounts.
Frame challenge 2: Don't use the same name when rebuilding a server. This isn't the only headache that will result from that.

We have control over the database server; we do not have control over Active Directory.  Changing the server name also requires adjusting external references outside our control.

I see the misunderstanding and have clarified in the question: "Later on, in general, how can we detect a Windows login SID is no longer valid so we know we need to recreate the login?"  If I could edit the earlier comment I would say, "managing the login is part of a separate scripted idempotent deployment process.  I suspect we both thought we were taking crazy pills here

@MarkSowul Yes, that detail is helpful, but again, why do you need to detect it later on as opposed to just making recreating the Login part of the original process? Do you not have control over the automated process?

Recreating the server was a rare/one-off manual event.  Ensuring the logins are set up correctly (dropping/recreating if necessary) is part of a separate, scripted push-button deployment/upgrade process.  In the scenario where the machine has been recreated, the login stops working and it's quite unintuitive.  Hence the desire to detect if a Windows login SID is actually invalid.  Nevertheless, this desire expands beyond any specific scenario, because in any case it is obscure and unintuitive to detect the mismatch

SUSER_SID does provide the correct SID if a login with that name does not exist, hence SQL has this ability at some level.  I was hoping there was some way to reach it

@MarkSowul Heads up, you should use @Username to alert people you're replying to otherwise they don't get a notification. Your last comment may clarify better. Are you saying the upgrade process you're trying to improve may run on a machine that was previously rebuilt at some point in the past, unrelated to the upgrade process?

After poking around some more, Solomon's answer here sparked an idea: create a SQLCLR function that takes in an account name and uses NTAccount / SecurityIdentifier to determine and emit the real SID.
This allows the calling code to work synchronously in SQL, without xp_cmdshell

There seems to be an assumption that the two "you"s in that sentence are the same person/process; they are not

This is not an accurate restatement of the question.  Also none of this discussion pertains to this answer.  I have directed the commentary back to the question

I think [sp_validatelogins] will only help with deleted Windows accounts, not those with a SID mismatch.
Here's a basic proof of concept using [xp_cmdshell] to call PowerShell. For those unable to use [xp_cmdshell] for security reasons, it could be re-written as a SQL Server Agent PowerShell Job Step, or entirely in a PowerShell script.
SID_BINARY() is undocumented so usual caveats apply.
SET NOCOUNT ON

EXEC sp_configure N'show advanced options', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure N'xp_cmdshell', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

/***********************************************************************/

DECLARE @output TABLE ([output] NVARCHAR(4000) NULL) ;

DECLARE @GroupName SYSNAME ;
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(4000) ;
DECLARE @WindowsSid NVARCHAR(4000) ;

SET @GroupName = N'group_name' ;

SET @stmt = N'powershell.exe -command "& {(Get-Localgroup @GroupName).SID | Select-Object "Value" }"' ;
SET @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, N'@GroupName', @GroupName) ;

INSERT INTO @output ([output])
EXEC xp_cmdshell @stmt = @stmt ;

SELECT TOP (1) @WindowsSid = [output]
FROM @output
WHERE [output] LIKE N'S-%' ;

SELECT 
   @WindowsSid AS WindowsSid, 
   SID_BINARY(@WindowsSid) AS WindowsBinary,
   [sid] AS SqlSid,
   CASE [sid]
      WHEN SID_BINARY(@WindowsSid) THEN N'OK'
      ELSE N'Mismatch'
   END AS [Result]
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE [type_desc] = N'WINDOWS_GROUP'
    AND RIGHT([name], LEN(N'\' + @GroupName)) = N'\' + @GroupName ;

/***********************************************************************/

EXEC sp_configure N'xp_cmdshell', 0 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure N'show advanced options', 0 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

/* If everything is OK */

WindowsSid    : S-1-5-21-1380299542-1474021980-1886381498-1005
WindowsBinary : 0x01050000000000051500000016B345525CCADB57BAE56F70ED030000
SqlSid        : 0x01050000000000051500000016B345525CCADB57BAE56F70ED030000
Result        : OK

/* If there is a problem */
/* 1005     vs. 1006     */
/* EE030000 vs. ED030000 */

WindowsSid    : S-1-5-21-1380299542-1474021980-1886381498-1006
WindowsBinary : 0x01050000000000051500000016B345525CCADB57BAE56F70EE030000
SqlSid        : 0x01050000000000051500000016B345525CCADB57BAE56F70ED030000
Result        : Mismatch


Appreciate the attempt -- unfortunately xp_cmdshell is off limits and using SQL agent means the whole process has to become asynchronous
